# Nested loop clarification - Edited

Tags: java

I'm an intro Java student, and I'm studying for a final exam. I'm going over a prior quiz on repetition statement loops, and see an answer I got wrong and cannot figure out for the life of me why the answer is the way it is.

Can someone please tell me why `z = 29` in the following case (and not `25`)? My Professor marked it wrong saying it was `29` but without explanation.

```
int z = 0;
for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
    for(int y=0; y<5;y++){
        z++;
    }
    z++;
}

z--;
```

The only way I was able to get `29` was by the inner loop executing `5` times (same for outer loop therefore, `5*5=25` plus 4?? Also I've executed this in my IDE and the console printed this when I tried `system.out.println(z);`

```
4
8
12
16
20
```

(so I'm now fairly confused) Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the accolades are correctly written? These have an important impact... If possible, can you make a scan of the assignment?

Comment: 20 is definitely the correct answer for the given program, but perhaps you forgot a few details.

Comment: z wouldn't amount to 25 or 29. It would amount to 20. If you moved your System.out.println out outside the loops, it would only print the last value: 20. You are executing a loop 5 times, which executes a loop 5 times. 5x5 = 25. subtracting one for every 5 you add, 5x5 - 5 = 20.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right there is a typo. Sorry!! I'm adding the correct code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fragment:

```
int z = 0;
for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
    for(int y=0; y<5;y++){
        z++;
    }
    z++;
}
z--;
```

Indeed results in `z` being equal to `29`. Lets calculate the difference for `z` for each part. The inner `for` loop iterates five times for each iteration of the outer loop so:

```
for(int y=0; y<5;y++){
    z++;
}
```

is basically equal to:

```
z += 5;
```

We thus rewrite the program to:

```
int z = 0;
for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
    z += 5;
    z++;
}
z--;
```

Now `z += 5;` and `z++` is equal to `z += 6;`. We rewrite the program to:

```
int z = 0;
for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
    z += 6;
}
z--;
```

The `for` loop is again repeated five times so the update for `z` is: `z += 5*6;` or `z += 30;`. We rewrite the program to:

```
int z = 0;
z += 30;
z--;
```

Finally we merge the three statements into one: `int z = 0+30-1;` or

```
int z = 29;
```

Comment: Thanks, Willem, I really really appreciate the detailed answer here! If it comes up again on the final, I will be ready for it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int z = 0;
// iterate 5 times
for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
    // iterate 5 times
    for(int y=0; y<5;y++){
        // z=z+1  
        z++;
    }
    // z=z-1
    z--;
}
```

Mathematically z=5*(5*(+1)-1)

Then z=20

Answer (score 0):

It runs through the inner loop 5 times for every increment in x. And for every increment of x.. adding up to a total of 5 times... it substracts one...

Therefore,

5*(5 + 1 )-1 = 29.

The answer is 20 not 29. Unless you have a typo.

Comment: I did have a typo. I apologize for that!

Comment: @PKM357 I edited my answer. hope it helps. Going for that Thumbs up^)^

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to upvote you but I need 15 reputation apparently to publicly change/upvote.

Comment: Its fine. No Problem. glad to help ! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure is 29 and not 20? Professors can have misleading writing styles at times.

The answer to the question should be 20

```
int z = 0;
for(int x=0; x<5;x++) //0 1 2 3 4  this loop will run 5 times
{ 
    for(int y=0; y<5;y++)//0 1 2 3 4  this loop will run 5 times
    { 
        z++; 
    }
    z--;
}
```

Answer is:
    z = outer loop * (inner loop - decrement)
    z = 5 * (5 - 1)
    z = 20

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 20. Perhaps his or her 20 looked like 29 while marking.

Answer (score 0):

With each iteration of the inner for loop z increases by 1. With each iteration of the outer for loop z decreases by 1.

Each time the inner loop loops five times, z is incremented by five.

Each time the outer loop completes one loop, z is decremented by one and the inner loop loops five times, therefore, z increments by 4 with each iteration of the outer loop.

The outer loop loops five times => (z+=4)*5 => z=20

***Edited***

With each iteration of the inner for loop z increases by 1. With each iteration of the outer for loop **(not including the inner loop) z also increases** by 1.

Each time the inner loop loops five times, z is incremented by five.

Each time the outer loop completes one loop, the inner loop loops five times and z is incremented by one, therefore, **z increments by 6** with each iteration of the outer loop.

The outer loop loops five times => (z+=6)*5 => z=30

And finally, you subtracted one at the very end, independently of the loops => z = 30 - 1 = **29**

Comment: sorry, I reedited the code, my mistake, can you reevaluate if it's actually 29?

Comment: @PKM357  There's the revised answer